Why doesnt the ask reflect my asking price when I put in a sell order below the listed ask?
Currently I am trying to sell some options on ThinkorSwim that have a bid x ask spread of $8 x $8.5. When I remove my ask, the spread widens so that the ask is in the $9 range so I am fairly confident that the $8.5 ask is me. However, my ask is $8.45, yet thinkorswim always reflects an ask that is $0.05 above what I entered. Do they enter a price slightly higher than what I will get paid so that they can keep the spread as a commission?

Brokerages are not required to place your order directly on an exchange as long as they fill it at a price that is the same as, or better than, the National Best Bid and Offer (NBBO). This is the highest bid and lowest ask for the security across all exchanges. Many brokerages will fill orders (especially smaller options orders) from their own inventory.
SEC Regulation NMS does not allow the brokerage to fill your order at a better price than your limit and pocket the difference.

But if the brokerage doesnt submit my order all the way to the order book then it doesnt hit the NBBO. I appreciate the explanation, but it still doesnt really answer why my order doesnt show up at my price. I have access to multiple different exchanges through TDAmeritrade/Schwab so it should show up
